# Does anyone know good Perl modules that can translate xml to json?

Tags: python, perl, module, cgi

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb
import httplib2
import xmltodict, json

cgitb.enable()

query = cgi.FieldStorage()
q_value = query["q"].value

h = httplib2.Http()
resp, content = h.request("http://192.168.1.13:8080/solr/select?q=" + q_value, "GET")

p_xml = xmltodict.parse(content)
json_r = json.dumps(p_xml)

print "Content-type: application/json"
print 
print json_r
```

I'm looking for comparable Perl modules to achieve the same effect, as I hear Perl is faster than Python doing these sort of things. The biggest ones here are obviously httplib2 and xmltodict, but the latter may just be because Python works well with dicts.

I'm very new to Perl and also new to programming in general, but Stack Overflow has been an incredible wealth of knowledge.

Comment: Faster doesn't mean better. Don't worry about speed until you can prove that it's a problem... and don't switch languages on heresay. And if you're just starting to program, stick with one language. I recommend Python.

Comment: The perl interpreter, may be faster than the python interpreter, but they're both interpreted languages and are thus both slow. If speed is a problem, switching to Perl won't gain you much. I love Perl (and I'm not a huge python fan), but if it works as is, and you don't yet know Perl, you have a compelling reason to leave it in Python. You'd gain more speed rewriting it in a non-interpreted language if that's your problem.

Comment: `as I hear Perl is faster than Python doing these sort of things` - If you aren't benchmarking it then how do you know if its "faster" _for your use case?_

Comment: Thank you both for the great advice! I wish I could just leave it in Python, but the boss says Perl is faster and that we will convert to a non-interpreted language later.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Unfortunately, I don't know. I also am not sure how to benchmark this situation, but I wonder if I'd want to poke the bear by doing it in the first place. :D

Comment: For a benchmark, I would factor out the network overhead, and use a couple of local samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't answer the question, but using Solr, you can add a `wt=json` parameter and it will return json rather than XML...

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON

Comment: If it doesn't answer the question, perhaps post it as a comment instead?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but is very good information as it allows me to not have to worry about the conversion. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried googling for `perl xml to json`? The first entry that shows up is [XML::XML2JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~ken/XML-XML2JSON-0.06/lib/XML/XML2JSON.pm).

Get the module, create a test case, and report your findings.